# How to create popups like that for MacOS application

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, popup

I am trying to create a MacOS to-do list app. I was wondering how to create a popup window similar to the screenshot when I click on a tableview cell.

(I tried searching for it before posting but didn't know what exactly it is called and didn't find much under tooltip/ popup)

Thanks!

**Image**

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: By default, when you click on a `UITableViewCell`, it just gets highlighted. You probably had some custom code running to show a "popup".

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is NSPopover